# Find an ideal $I$ in $A$ so that $A/I$ is a finite field with $25$ elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, finite-fields, maximal-and-prime-ideals, polynomial-rings

> Let $A = \frac {\Bbb Z[X]} {\left ( X^4+X^2+1 \right )}.$ Find an ideal $I$ in $A$ such that $A/I$ is a finite field with $25$ elements.

I have seen that the polynomial $X^4+X^2+1$ is reducible in $\Bbb Z[X]$ since $$X^4+X^2+1 = \left ( X^2+X+1 \right ) \left ( X^2-X+1 \right ).$$ So by Chinese remainder theorem in ring theory we have $$\frac {\Bbb Z[X]} {\left ( X^4+X^2+1 \right )} \cong \frac {\Bbb Z[X]} {\left ( X^2+X+1 \right )} \times \frac {\Bbb Z[X]} {\left ( X^2-X+1 \right )} \cong \Bbb Z[\omega] \times \Bbb Z[\omega].$$

How do I prove the above result using the fact that $$\frac {\Bbb Z[X]} {\left ( X^4+X^2+1 \right )} \cong \Bbb Z[\omega] \times \Bbb Z[\omega].$$

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: It may be more obvious how to make one of $\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ and $\Bbb{Z}[x]/\langle x^2-x+1\rangle$ disappear.

Comment: Can you help me @Jyrki Lahtonen?

Comment: How do you make one factor disappear from $A=\Bbb{Z}/\langle 6\rangle$ to find an ideal $I$ such that $A/I\simeq \Bbb{Z}/\langle 3\rangle$? It may or may not help to think of $A$ as $\Bbb{Z}/\langle 2\rangle\times \Bbb{Z}/\langle 3\rangle$ as per Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: In this case I think $I=3 \Bbb Z/6 \Bbb Z$ will do the trick. Isn't it so @Jyrki Lahtonen?

Comment: So in my case $I=\frac {\left (5,X^2+X+1 \right )} {\left (X^4+X^2+1 \right )}$ will do the trick. Am I right @Jyrki Lahtonen?

Comment: Correct. Why don't you post the details as an answer! Then you get more feedback! Anyway, the main thing is that you see the light :-)

Comment: You are very helpful sir. I have no word to explain gratitude to you. Thank you very much @Jyrki Lahtonen sir for your kind cooperation.

Comment: For some reason no one has noticed that we can not use the Chinese Remainder Theorem since the ideals $I=(X^2+X+1)$ and $J=(X^2-X+1)$ are not coprime in $\mathbb Z[X]$.

Comment: Indeed, @user26857 pointed out a shortcoming. The fact that we are looking at quotients of polynomial rings over $\Bbb{Z}$ rather than a field makes a difference in the sense that constants are not units.

Answer (score 2):

We want to try to use your idea.

Third isomorphism theorem for rings: Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals of the ring $R$, with $I \subseteq J$. Then $J/I$ is an ideal of $R/I$, and $R/J \cong (R/I)/(J/I)$.

Here,  $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1)$, that is, the ideal generated by $x^2+x+1$ contains the ideal generated by $x^4+x^2+1$.

Hence, $(x^2+x+1,5)/(x^4+x^2+1)=P$ is an ideal of $A$.

Then $A/P \cong \Bbb{F}_{25}$.

Hope, this will help. Looking for the improvement.

Comment: This is a valid answer. No idea why it was downvoted. (+1)